# Using Margin Images in HTML?

Tags: html, image, margin

I know a lot of HTML but it's all been self-taught and I keep running into these unkowns when trying to make sites that look how I actually want them to.

I want to make my site a minimum of 940 px wide- if the browser is less than this in width, users will have to scroll horizontally.

If the browser is more than 940 px wide however- I want images to appear to "connect" with my header image(show as a full width header) and nav image(show as a full width nav).

Check out the attachment to see what I mean.
Sean

http://i45.tinypic.com/2n862ys.png

[image: Image and video hosting by TinyPic]

Answer (score 1):

In CSS:

```
 header{ min-width: 940px; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
 .headerImage { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Then in HTML:

```
<header>
    <img class="headerImage" src="./Images/HeaderImage.png" alt="" />
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a image larger than the 940px that you would like as your width then you could just set the background position of your image to be centered so if it increases or decreases the image wont move just the amount that is shown.

Another method could be is to repeat the background image so it wont end... but that depends on what sort of image you are using...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<style type="text/css">
img {
  min-width:940px;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
</style>
```